# move file with same as folder name

Tags: linux

how to move file with same name as folder

for example:

```
#ls
total 2
.
..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root      230 Jan 16 10:39   food <file to move>
drwx--x--x 12 root     root     4096 Jan 16 11:25   food <directory>
```

i want to move food into food directory.

final output should be `food/food.ini`

when i use `#mv food food/food.ini` there an error

```
mv: cannot move `food' to a subdirectory of itself, `food/food.ini'
```

**update:**

this file created using following commands:

```
cp foods1 ../food
```

where food folder is available at parent directory.

i can move using webmin. but the file not exists when trying to edit using vi editor.

Comment: Is this a real problem or a theoretical situation? If a real problem, how did this happen? Linux will typically not permit you to create a file and directory with the same name inside the same parent directory.

Comment: i created using cp food1 ../food

Comment: i can move using webmin. but not sure to move that file using command line. if possible how webmin can move for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
find ./ -name food -type f -exec mv {} ./food/{} \;
```

Comment: i already deleted the file and cannot reproduce the problem. this is acceptable answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot duplicate the method you used to create a file and a directory with the same name in the same folder, but you can clean up the situation by moving the file using its inode number rather than its name through something like the find command.

```
[jpaulus@localhost test]$ ls -lhi
total 4.0K
26086760 drwxrwxr-x 2 jpaulus jpaulus 4.0K Jan 15 23:19 test
26086768 -rw-rw-r-- 1 jpaulus jpaulus    0 Jan 15 23:19 test1

find . -inum 26086760 -exec mv {} new_directory/new_filename \;

[jpaulus@localhost test]$ ls -lh
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jpaulus jpaulus 0 Jan 15 23:19 test1
```

Comment: thanks for -lhi command. can i move file using inode number?

Comment: ok its can: http://www.labtestproject.com/linuxcmd/mv.html